# Format references in German (not only the title)

Tags: bibliographies, languages

My literature entries are formatted in English despite the use of `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. For example, it says "Author1 *and* Author2" but I want it "Author1 *und* Author2". "Literatur" instead of "References" however works.

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \citep{DoeMustermann2014}.

\cleardoublepage
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

`test.bib`:

```
@book{DoeMustermann2014,
  title = {{That awful German language}},
  Author= {John Doe and Max Mustermann},
  publisher = {English-German Friendship},
  address = {Hamburg - New York},
  Year  = {2014}
}
```

Comment: Strange... because I do. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04, using Kile.

Comment: And what do you see instead if I may ask?

Comment: I think there is no way for that without some hacking in the installed natbib files. It is quite outdated. Did you tried `biber` with `biblatex`?

Comment: `natbib` is outdated? Didn't know that. I'll look around for `biber` - never heard.

Comment: See also this question (not an exact duplicate, but providing more answers): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279591/bibtex-using-the-wrong-language

Comment: I would suggest switching to BibLaTeX. It automatically uses the language specified for the `babel` package in the bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agsm-Style uses a command for the and. So you are in luck and can adapt it (but biblatex/biber is naturally much more flexible):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\harvardand{und}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \citep{DoeMustermann2014}.

\cleardoublepage
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on the position in the text, one must use `\renewcommand\harvardand{und}`.

Answer (score 1):

The `babel` package localises the normal LaTeX settings, but not the thingies coming from BibTeX. You need a localised BibTeX style (bst) for this purpose. e.g., `natdin.bst`.