# Bibtex using the wrong language!

Tags: bibtex, languages

I need to type a bibliography to my final graduation work (in brazilian portuguese) and I am facing a problem with BibTeX. Whenever I add in information like "Edition", it doesn't translate the word "Edition" to "Edição" when compiling. I've been trying to follow advices from other forums and I don't seem to be having any luck. Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}

\cite{Boulos}
\end{document}
```

The contents of my `biblio.bib` file are below:

```
@book{Boulos,
author    = "BOULOS, Paulo",
title     = "C\'{a}lculo Diferencial e Integral",
publisher = "Pearson Makron Books",
volume   = "1",
address  = "S\~{a}o Paulo",
edition  = "1",
year      = "1999",
note     = "380 p",
}
```

So how can I get it to translate the words like "Edition" to "Edição"? Also, when I compile this, I get what seems to be a subitem, as if this entry in the bibliography had subentries, but that's not the case, how can I disable that?

Thanks in advance, my deadline is near and if I can't figure a way around, I'll need to swap back to MS Word to continue this work.

Comment: I would suggest switching to BibLaTeX. It automatically uses the language specified for the `babel` package in the bibliography.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `babplain` for a babel-aware version of `plain` part of the `babelbib` package see `texdoc babelbib` for more details.

You also need to add

```
\usepackage{babelbib}
```

so that it defines all the new fixed texts in an appropriate language.

Comment: One last detail. I still get the annoying "subitem" after the reference. Something like [1] - first reference and then I get a subitem [1] to that, but empty.

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas sorry I can't guess, feel free to make a new question with an example document. (It's always best to open a new question rather than ask followup questions in comments, by design the site formatting makes it hard to discuss code in comments:-)

Answer (score 8):

Find `plain.bst` on your file system, copy the file, rename the file to something else. Open the file, add a comment that the name has changed and the current year and preferrably your name.

Find the edition function and replace it with the following block:

```
FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { edition "l" change.case$ " Edi\c{c}\~ao" * }
        { edition "t" change.case$ " Edi\c{c}\~ao" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Save your file. Put it in the same folder as your tex document (for now).

Change your document to use the new modified bibliographystyle.

Done.

---

Or use biblatex, it picks up the language used in the doument.

Comment: I upvoted your answer: I'm sure it'd come in handy if I were to customize other details (and I will). I'm not familiar with biblatex so the simplest solution was to use babplain, but thanks a lot for your help!