# Change language in references

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, languages

I'm writing a report in Swedish and I have IEEE references using BibTex.
The problem is that the program wants to use English words in references such as "[online]" and "available". I don't want those English words since the report is in Swedish.

Does anyone have a solution?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,swedish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{IEEEabrv.bib}
@ONLINE {regeringen,
author = "Regeringskansliet",
title  = "Mål för förnybar energi", 
year   = "2014",
url    = "http://www.regeringen.se/regeringens-politik/energi/fornybar-energi/mal-for-fornybar-energi/"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can edit a renamed copy of `IEEEtran.bst` search for the relevant strings (e.g. in `FUNCTION {default.name.url.prefix}{ "[Online]. Available:" }`) change them and use the new BibTeX style instead the original one. But I would recommend to switch over to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) that is prepared to use strings in the main language of the document.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279591/bibtex-using-the-wrong-language

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.