# Swedish: reference list

Tags: bibtex, languages, sharelatex

I've written a manuscript (using `classicthesis` package) in ShareLaTeX. It looks great. But I have one problem: 
In the reference list 'and' appears instead of 'och' (Swedish for 'and') between authors, I found a remedy that requires editing a `.bst` file. Is it possible to do that within ShareLaTeX?

I am using the `unsrt` style. (Don't know if that matters.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In this case [minimal but working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) would be helpful. But before have a look to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279591/bibtex-using-the-wrong-language. And I would even recommend to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with [`biber`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biber) instead of the old `bibtex` system. Normally `biblatex` automatically uses document language.

Comment: BTW: Could not find `usrnt.bst`. Do you mean `unsrt.bst`?

Comment: You should not edit a distribution file without renaming it. You can add files to ShareLaTeX projects. So adding a renamed (and changed) version of the file to your project and use this instead of the original one should be possible.

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex`? It cooperates with `babel`.

Comment: biblatex did the trick. \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex} produced something close to what I first intended.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from Bernard to use `biblatex` did the trick. The command
`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblat‌​ex}` produced something close to what I first intended.