# BibTeX still using the wrong language

Tags: bibtex, babel, harvard-style

I've tried the advice given here: [Bibtex using the wrong language!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279591/bibtex-using-the-wrong-language)
and here: [Format references in German (not only the title)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276767/format-references-in-german-not-only-the-title?lq=1)
and I have read the babelbib manual.

But still I do not get the desired references (with, e.g., "Hrsg" or something similar instead of "editor").

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babelbib}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} 
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}%dcu%agsm
\selectbiblanguage{german}
\bibliography{Literatur} 
\nocite{AristotleNEde}
\end{document}
```

(I have also tried to get biber/biblatex to work but have been running into other difficulties there.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)!

Comment: I don't think `babelbib` is compatible with `harvard`

Comment: Interesting! Commenting 
`\usepackage{harvard}`
does not make a difference, though.

Comment: If you are writing a thesis and do not rely on a journal, i would use `biblatex` as advised on [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html).  You are looking for something like `style=authoryear`.

Comment: It is only for a brief research proposal that I wish to get done with soon. But I get the impression it might be worth investing time in the future to get accustomed to biblatex properly (I had a first go with it but it did not work). Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: I would suggest switching to BibLaTeX. It automatically uses the language specified for the `babel` package in the bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: Search for the file

> where_ever_your_tex_dristibution_is/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/harvard/dcu.bst

copy it to your working directory, rename the copy to, e.g., `dcu_NCH32.bst`, and replace the two occurrences of `" (eds)"` with whatever you want.

Than invoke the modified style with `\bibliographystyle{dcu_NCH32}`

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint! I edited the answer.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your answer a bit more. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea -- I could not put it into practice, as I did not find the required file. I have two folders named 'bibtex' on my hard drive, neither contains a subfolder called 'bst', or a file named 'dcu.bst'. I also searched TeXShop.

Comment: @NCH32 What do you get, if you type `which latex` in a terminal?

Comment: @NCH32 alternatively, you can download the file from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/?lang=en

Comment: I get `/usr/texbin/bibtex`....?

Comment: @NCH32 Have you tried to download the file from ctan? That is probably the easiest.

Comment: @NCH32 mmm, I hoped to see the location of the actual tex distribution. Downloading is probably easiest, alternatively look at the `.log` of your document, there you can find the location of your packages, e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty`, this means you should be able to find the file at `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/harvard/`.

Comment: This works! Thanks so much :) 
For the record: in my case, the relevant lines were lines 240 onwards in `dcu_mod.bst`